# How enable/disable <p:tab> without update form?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a big <h:form>, with a <p:tabView> with 3 <p:tab>
I want to enable/disable one <p:tab> based on <p:selectOneRadio> click.

How can I achieve this without updating the entire form?

```
<p:selectOneRadio id = "pessoa" required = "true"
  value="#{myBean.typeChecked}" valueChangeListener="#{myBean.checkTypeSelec}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="item 1" itemValue="PF" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="item 2" itemValue="PJ" />
  <p:ajax event="click" update="???" execute="@this"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:tab title="History"  id="historyTab" disabled="#{myBean.historyDisabled}">...
```

I dont wanna update entire form because I dont wanna loose other inputs data

Comment: Update the `p:tabView`?

Comment: You're right! Thank's a lot!